# Unix-Echo -n is not working

Tags: shell, solaris

```
for(( i=0;i<=5;i++))
do
    for ((j=1;j<=i;j++))
    do
        echo -n "$j"
    done 
    echo " "
done
```

Outputs:

```
-n 1

-n 1
-n 2

-n 1
-n 2
-n 3

-n 1
-n 2
-n 3
-n 4

-n 1
-n 2
-n 3
-n 4
-n 5
```

My OS: SunOS sun4v sparc sun4v

I want the output to be:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: What shell scripting language are you using? Edit your question and add it to the tags.

Comment: This works correctly in bash and bash's sh emulation mode. It is not even valid syntax in zsh. As you have not specified what shell you are using it's not possible to give you straight answer or fix yet. Please [edit] your question to include that detail.

Comment: Try `printf`... `echo -n "$j"` -> `printf "$j"`

Comment: What do you get from 
echo $SHELL;
echo $BASH_VERSION;
which echo;
echo --version;

Comment: ksh is a default shell in Solarises AFAI remember. but it's still working in ksh too. do `echo $0`

Comment: @anishsane **Never** use `printf "$j"`; you meant `printf %s "$j"`.

Comment: ^^ My bad, yes I meant `printf %s "$j"`...

Answer (score 7):

According to [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/echo-1.html#scrolltoc), the `-n` option to `echo` is not portable. On a Solaris system `-n` is supported by the BSD emulation of `echo` in `/usr/ucb/echo`, but not by the default `echo`. As a result:

> `ksh88`'s and `ksh`'s `echo` does not have an `-n` option. `csh`'s echo and `/usr/ucb/echo`, on the other hand, have an `-n` option, but do not understand the back-slashed escape characters. `sh` and `ksh88` determine whether `/usr/ucb/echo` is found first in the PATH and, if so, they adapt the behavior of the echo builtin to match `/usr/ucb/echo`.

To fix the problem, you have several options:

1. Switch to `printf %s "$j"` to portably print a string without newline. (I would recommend doing this.)
2. Switch to `\c` escapes, i.e. replace `echo -n "$j"` with `echo "$j\c"`. (Not recommended if the script needs to remain portable to BSD systems.)
3. Download a well-tested free shell such as `bash` that implements `echo -n`, and use it to run the shell scripts you care about.
4. Prepend `/usr/ucb` to the `PATH`. This will cause `echo` to switch to BSD-compliant behavior, but will also introduce other BSD commands, potentially breaking unrelated parts of the script. (Not recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

If `-n` option is not working for you, you can try using `-e` option which enables the use of backslash characters and then you can use `\c` in your `echo` statement.
Here is the code sample:

```
    for(( i=0;i<=5;i++))
    do
        for ((j=1;j<=i;j++))
           do
               echo -e "$j \c"
          done
        echo " "
   done
```